# How does Jetpack Compose create the view to user？

Tags: android, view, android-jetpack-compose

In traditional Android app, if you want to show a TextView, you can inflate a file of xml which contains a TextView. You run the app, then you will see the TextView.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_finish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="finish_button"
        />
```

When I use compose, I don't know how the Compose create the view? Does it use Android native view in bottom layer? Or, does Compose create a new view system different from traditional Android to show the view?

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.clickable { isExpand = !isExpand }
) {
    Text(
        text = msg.author, color = Color.DarkGray,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
    )
}
```

You can use the code above and say something. Thanks.

Edit:

I create a page follow [Jetpack Compose Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial).
[image]

Then I check Layout Inspector in Android Studio, I don't find traditional Android View in Component tree.
[image]

You can see from the picture. The node's names are function name of compose, eg. Text()、Button()、Column(), etc.

Dose it use Traditional Android View to show actually?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an android app with Compose Activity you will see **senContentView** method has been replaced by **setContent{}**
Then in Source Code of this function you see below code:

```
public fun ComponentActivity.setContent(
    parent: CompositionContext? = null,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val existingComposeView = window.decorView
        .findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
        .getChildAt(0) as? ComposeView

    if (existingComposeView != null) with(existingComposeView) {
        setParentCompositionContext(parent)
        setContent(content)
    } else ComposeView(this).apply {
        // Set content and parent **before** setContentView
        // to have ComposeView create the composition on attach
        setParentCompositionContext(parent)
        setContent(content)
        // Set the view tree owners before setting the content view so that the inflation process
        // and attach listeners will see them already present
        setOwners()
        setContentView(this, DefaultActivityContentLayoutParams)
    }
}
```

At the end you see traditional Android SetContentView :

**setContentView(this, DefaultActivityContentLayoutParams)**

So it uses old way. but thinking in compose is functional programming Despite of XML base that is OOP.

Comment: hi, I append some pictures for my question. I don't see any Android native view in layout inspector. How to explain this phenomenon？Thanks.

Comment: On layout inspector composables are independent from Android View Component,because of some concept like recomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Actually composable get composed on the screen at the very root level like pixels level. There are some answers to the question like

> How a kotlin function is behave like View ?

We define a function with the `@Composable` annotation by this way we tells the compiler that this is a composable to render on the screen. And wherever we used this function it draws the composable on the screen.

> rendering on screen where we control it ?

Yes you guess it right we only set the composable once using `setContent` but the composable function is recomposed several times on the screen sometimes due to the states changed in the root level or from UI side and that's why you have noticed that we use `remember` lambda to remember state that are changed due to recomposition.

> ClickListener vs Modifier :/

You might also noticed that in the XML we have ClickListener and for a view that doesn't support the click we have to do some more hard work and use more apis. But as you know that composable is drawing over the screen at the pixel level so every pixel can get the click and at the point where the user clicks if there is any composable then the `Modifier` of that composable starts working.

> It means the android doesn't use traditional View ?

It uses as you can see the definition of `setContent` but the purpose is to set the window or platform for the composable *but that also doesn't mean that the XML layouts are used behind the scenes.*

Comment: maybe I can't understand "composable" deeply in concept. I hope you can make something for example to explain the "composable" clearly and obviously. Thanks.

Comment: @SnailBird You can can have a look to this article for a better understanding: https://medium.com/@banmarkovic/jetpack-compose-under-the-hood-7bb88f08c47e